# Как правильно делать запрос на сервер Fetch Api через циклы

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, fetch

Делаю запрос на сервер через метод map  потом те данные я устанавливаю в State и использую для вывода информации  но иногда проскакивают баги, я  знаю что я что то не правильно делаю но не могу понять как, напишите как правильно организовать запрос и потом  отрендерить компонент

```
const urlList = ["countries", "states", "cities", "users"];

componentDidMount() {
     urlList.map( (url, index) => {
        return servicesAPI.getResourse(url).then( (body) => {
            index !== 3 ?  this.setState({
                             dataAPI : [...this.state.dataAPI, body] }) :
                            this.setState({
                                dataAPI : [...this.state.dataAPI, body],
                                loaded: true
                            })

        })
    })

}

export default  class ServicesAPI {
_apiBase = `http://localhost:3001/`;


async getResourse(url) {
    const res = await fetch(`${this._apiBase}${url}`);

    if (!res.ok) {
        throw new Error(`Could not fetch ${url}` +
            `, received ${res.status}`)
    }
    return await res.json();
}
```

Comment: запросы должны быть параллельными или последовательными?

Comment: последовательными... исправил.. каждый запрос один за одным

Comment: тогда map тут не подойдет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы вызвать fetch после вызова первого запроса, вы должны вызвать его в then() первого запроса.

```
fetch(url).then(() => fetch(url).then(...))
```

Answer (score 0):

Дали ответ на другом ресурсе мне помог

```
 async componentDidMount() {
    for (const url of urlList) {
        const
            dataAPI = [ ...this.state.dataAPI, await servicesAPI.getResourse(url) ],
            loaded = dataAPI.length === urlList.length;

        await new Promise(r => this.setState({ dataAPI, loaded }, r));
    }
}
```

Comment: последней строке не нужен await и new Promise